# Encode column of lists into integer in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, encoding

I have a pyspark dataframe like this one:

```
 --------------------
| id | configuration |
|----|---------------|
| 1  | [c1, c2, a1]  |
| 2  | [c1, c2, a1]  |
| 3  | [z1, x6, a8]  |
 --------------------
```

I want to encode the configuration column into a column of integer, the following is the desired  dataframe:

```
 -----------------------------
| id | configuration | labels |
|----|---------------|--------|
| 1  | [c1, c2, a1]  |    1   |
| 2  | [c1, c2, a1]  |    1   |
| 3  | [z1, x6, a8]  |    2   |
 -----------------------------
```

How can i perform this operation?

Comment: In addition to that i would like to perform another labeling which consider the list of configuration as sets and not as lists. To give an exmaple, the configurations: [a1,a2,c1] and [a2,c1,a1], must have the encoded integer according to this type of labeling.

Comment: Why id1 and id2 are the value 1 in labels ? Because they are equals ?

Comment: because the repsective configuration columns are identical

Answer (score 1):

Window functions, dense_rank()

```
df.withColumn('labels', dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('configuration'))).show()

+---+-------------+------+
| id|configuration|labels|
+---+-------------+------+
|  1| [c1, c2, a1]|     1|
|  2| [c1, c2, a1]|     1|
|  3| [z1, x6, a8]|     2|
+---+-------------+------+
```